# How do I pass a value to a site called by jquery using RESTful Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, rest

I have a Ruby on Rails page that loads another page using jquery. I want to pass a parameter "site" to the page via REST, for example:

```
sitetotals/(site)
```

instead of the old way with php:

```
sitetotals?site=(site)
```

In my routes.rb file I have:

```
resources :sitetotals
match '/sitetotals', to: 'sitetotals#site'
```

What's the best way to do this using Rails? I'm running Rails 3.2.1, and I'm not sure how to pass the parameter to the controller for sitetotals or if that's even the best practice. Do I put my query in the model or the controller?

Comment: You should put your JS code (i.e. jQuery) into View, helper or event in resource *.js file (generally as a function or method on class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your route like this :

```
# routes.rb
match 'sitetotals/:site' => 'sitetotals#site'
```

In your controller the `site` parameter will be available in the `params` hash.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly it. It's able to post the site parameter to the sitetotals page now.

Answer (score 1):

In restful routes you can write an additional route using either `member` or `collection`.

We generally define a `collection` route for generic things, eg: search of all users. We define `member` route for a particular resource, eg: route for profile preview of user resource. You can read more on [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions).

So if you are looking for member route, its gonna be like this,

```
resources :sitetotals do
  member do
    get 'site'
  end
end
```